# Bison-Flex extern FILE *yyin isn't working (C language)

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-errors, bison, flex-lexer

I know that in flex you just have to do `yyin = fopen(filename, "r");` to read a file but if you want to do it from bison how is it possible? I'm trying to combine flex and bison for my purpose(read a file with `4 + 5 + 7;` and print the outcome) but I have a hard time trying to open a file from bison. I tried to use `extern FILE *yyin` at the declaration room and after that `yyin = fopen(filename, "r");` but I got the error:

> C2065: 'yyin' : undeclared identifier.

This is my code just in case it helps to find it.

bison code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
extern FILE *yyin;
int yyerror(char *message)
{
    return 0;
}
%}

%union {
 double val;
 char sym;
}   
%token <val> NUMBER
%token <sym> PLUS Q_MARK
%type <val> addition_list addition
%start addition_list
%%

addition_list : addition Q_MARK  {printf("apotelesma: %d\n", $1);}
| addition_list addition Q_MARK  {}
;

addition : NUMBER PLUS NUMBER {$$ = $1 + $3;}
| addition PLUS NUMBER {$$ = $1 + $3;}
;

%%
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen("argv[1]", "r");
    yyparse();
}
```

flex code:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "flex2.tab.h"
%}

%%
\+ { flex2lval.sym = yytext[0];printf("%c\n", yytext[0]);  return PLUS; }
; { flex2lval.sym = yytext[0]; return Q_MARK; }
0|([-+]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|(0\.[0-9]+)|([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))) {flex2lval.val = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
%%
```

Comment: I don't remember exactly because it's before 1 year.The code was ok, the problem was somewhere in the options of the compiler.

Comment: Your `yyerror()` method should print that message (which will always say `"syntax error"` unless you're calling it yourself. Merely returning zero isn't helpful to the user.

Comment: This is a *compiler error.* Not a case of 'not working' at all. And why are you treating `;` as a Q_MARK?

Answer (score -1):

Did you compile the file that flex produced along with the file bison produced?

`flex lexical_file.l` (produces lex.yy.c)

`bison -d syntax_file.y` (produces syntax_file.tab.c and syntax_file.tab.h)

```
gcc syntax_file.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -o myparser.out
```

Also you should remove the quotes around "argv[1]". It should be `yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");` if you want to successfully open the file that was passed as the first argument to the parser instead of trying to open a file that is actually **named** "argv[1]".

Comment: All true but he got a compiler error, not a linker error.